# Navigation-based app with TabBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm using *Navigation-based Application* Template with Core Data. Could anyone please tell me how to and a TabBar on the bottom of the view. I am using `UITableView`, so If I add `UITabBar` as subview, the TabBar is moving along with tableView when scrolling. I would like to switch between views with TabBar, first "segment" of TabBar should open the RootView (NavigationBar with TableView),and second some other view.

Now I did this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewController = [NSArray arrayWithObject:yourNavigationController];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController
[tabBarController release];
```

that works fine, but how can I add more Items to `UITabBar` and for each Item some other view? TabBar has now just one Item on which rootView is loaded
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITabBarController` as your root view controller in your application delegate:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewController = [NSArray arrayWithObject:yourNavigationController];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController
[tabBarController release];
```

Comment: that works fine, but how can I add more items to TabBar, and for each item some other View. TabBar has now just one item, where rootView is loaded

Comment: You can add as many view controllers as you line. Just add few move items into NSArray on line #2 of code above.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple one, just add UITabbarController to your code and then made the first tab controller to be a navigation controller. And point that navigation controller to your controller which has table view that you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it programmatically you can use this:

```
FirstViewController *first=[FirstViewController alloc]]init];
UINavigationController *nav=[UINavigationController alloc]]initwithRootViewcontroller:first];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewController = [NSArray arrayWithObject:first];

[tabBarController release];
```